# For each unique key in a table do a select statement

Tags: sql-server, join, dynamic

I have One table, containing both `operators` and `operatorgroups`.
Operators are linked to 'operatorgroups' via a link table.
Now, for each 'operatorgroup' I would like to select the operators linked to it.

It needs to be dynamic, so when a new 'operatorgroup' is created I don't have to adjust the query.

What I do now is repeat the following query to list the names of the operators and the 'operatorgroup' name, but I have to rewrite the query every time I add an 'operatorgroup'.
How can I make the same query for all distinct 'operatorgroups'

```
SELECT Distinct A.[ref_dynanaam], A.[naam] 
FROM [dbo].[actiedoor] A  
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[actiedoorlink] B 
ON B.[actiedoorid]=A.[unid] 
OR B.[actiedoorgroepid] = A.[unid]
WHERE B.[actiedoorgroepid] ='unid' AND status >='1' 
order by A.[naam] Desc
```

This gives me

**ref_Dynanaam**                **Naam**
Makelaars   Makelaars
Eyk, Johan van
Hoetmer, JanR
Rooijen, Manon van

Note that only Coaches appears twice.
I would like said list for all 'operatorgroups' (for each distinct b.actiedoorgroepid)
**Screenshot 1** 
Cannot post screenshots due to to0 few reputation points
= a subsection from the 'actiedoor' and actiedoorlink tables
**Screenshot 2**
Cannot post screenshots due to to0 few reputation points
= the result of the above mentioned query

Another edit:
So, I'm one step further.
By executing the following query I get sort of what I need:

```
SELECT Distinct A.[ref_dynanaam], A.[naam], B.[actiedoorgroepid] 
FROM [dbo].[actiedoor] A 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[actiedoorlink] B 
ON B.[actiedoorid]=A.[unid] 
OR B.[actiedoorgroepid] = A.[unid] 
WHERE (B.[actiedoorgroepid] 
IN (Select DISTINCT B.[actiedoorgroepid]from actiedoorlink as B 
WHERE B.[actiedoorgroepid] = B.[actiedoorgroepid])  AND A.[status] >='1') 
GROUP BY B.[actiedoorgroepid], A.[naam], A.[ref_dynanaam]
```

This gives me:

**ref_Dynanaam naam actiedoorgroepid**
Hoetmer, Jan        4e0001
Leurink, Rob        4e0001
Rooijen, Manon van  4e0001
Soodoo, Adjai       4e0001
Ideeenmanagement Ideeenmanagement 4e0001
Eyk, Johan van      4a0002
Hoetmer, Jan        4a0002
Rooijen, Manon van 4a0002
Makelaars Makelaars 4a0002

Now, for each row in the result set I need to execute another subquery.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take a different approach and forget about the entire query. Instead I decided to make a simple query and use the filtering system in the program I was using to get the data I needed.
Thanks for the assitance though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a self join

```
SELECT A.[actiedoorid] AS [operatorid],A.[unid] 
FROM [dbo].[actiedoorlink] A
JOIN [dbo].[actiedoorlink] B  
ON A.[actiedoorgroepid]=B.[actiedoorgroepid]
```